# Saving bytes into temporary file in c#

Tags: c#, file, stream, temporary-files

I want to save incomming byte stream into a temporary created mp3 file, that later plays. I do have it working, if I save entire array, but I want it to be adding bytes in as they are received. The code I use to play an entire byte array is like this:

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
Java.IO.File temp = Java.IO.File.CreateTempFile("temp", "mp3");
temp.DeleteOnExit();

Java.IO.FileOutputStream fos = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(temp);
fos.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
fos.Close();

Java.IO.FileInputStream fis = new Java.IO.FileInputStream(temp);
player.SetDataSource(fis.FD);
player.Prepare();
player.Start();
```

But I would like to know, how, I could be writting it inside a while loop. I tried this, but nothing happens.

```
MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
Java.IO.File temp = Java.IO.File.CreateTempFile("temp", "mp3");
temp.DeleteOnExit();

Java.IO.FileOutputStream fos = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(temp);
Java.IO.FileInputStream fis = new Java.IO.FileInputStream(temp);

player.Start();


while (mmInStream.IsDataAvailable())
{
    mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
    fos.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
    player.SetDataSource(fis.FD);
    player.Prepare();
    player.Start();
}
```

So I tried to put the player.Start() infront of the while loop, but nothing happens again. Would the SetDataSource need to be infront of the, but would that work if the bytes were added later, than it was inputed into the player.

---

So i tried to recreate MediaPlayer each time, and I do get the music playing(but not from the start), for a couple of seconds, but than I have to press the button, to check for messages again, and than it continious for a couple of seconds. So how would I make it to continue reading. My read code now is like this:

```
public void Read()
{
    System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
    {

        try
        {
            byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[100000];

            //while (mmInStream.IsDataAvailable())
            //{
                mmInStream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
                Java.IO.File temp = Java.IO.File.CreateTempFile("temp", "txt");
                temp.DeleteOnExit();

                Java.IO.FileOutputStream fos = new Java.IO.FileOutputStream(temp);
                fos.Write(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);
                fos.Close();

                Java.IO.FileInputStream fis = new Java.IO.FileInputStream(temp);

                player.SetDataSource(fis.FD);
                player.Prepare();
                player.Start();
            //}
        }
        catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Input stream was disconnected", ex);
        }


    }).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

Comment: Could you define "nothing happens"? Is nothing added or nothing played?

Comment: **Java**.IO.File ? In C#?

Comment: @MarioTheSpoon Nothing is being played, how would I check what data the file contains?

Comment: @Fildor It is used in xamarin.forms

Comment: @MTS check in explorer (do not forget to refresh) and try to play in external mp3 player. My guess is that the stream used for replaying is not checked again once it reached the end (in the first loop). You could try to re-create the player in each loop.

Comment: @MTS Ah, ok. I was really confused. Since Xamarin has its quirks, your should mention that you are using it in the question.